# Rotating tileBitmap based on its direction

Tags: java, android

How can I rotate the tileBitmap based on it's direction given the code below ? How can I achieve this ?

```
public TileGraphics(int x, int y, InputStream is) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        if(this.currentDirection == Direction.LEFT)
        tileBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(), (int)tileSize, (int)tileSize, true);

        if (is != null) {
            tileBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is), (int) tileSize, (int) tileSize, true); // boolean statement at the end good for bilinear filtering
        }

        if (is != null && this.currentDirection == Direction.LEFT) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
            tileBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileBitmap, 0, 0, tileBitmap.getWidth(), tileBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything correct given the code above ? Or are there other helpful links to solve this question ?

My idea is that I can rotate the tileBitmap based on the direction it is heading and change the image to either right,left,up,down.

Answer (score 0):

```
// EDIT: added forgotten if statement
if (this.currentDirection == Direction.IDLE) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
        tileBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileBitmap, 0, 0, tileBitmap.getWidth(), 
        tileBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true)
}
```

This code worked for changing the direction of an image when working with threads.